# want navbar to shift from nav-items to button based off size

Tags: html, css, web

is there a way to make a navbar that has nav-items listed if long enough, but will turn into a nav-toggle button on give a dropdown if on a short

currently only have a implementation of a offcanvas dropdown

Answer (score 1):

The width of the elements can always be detected at runtime in JavaScript, provided that the width of the menu in question can change dynamically, so we cannot rely on a fixed value, such as 678px, because the menu can sometimes be smaller or larger. In the attached code snippet, I have detailed my solution.

In my solution, JavaScript performs the check only when the page loads, but of course, it is possible to monitor changes in the page width as well. It's up to you to decide how you want to implement this.

### Example

```js
const navbar = document.getElementById('nav');
const navbarItems = document.getElementById('nav-items');

// if navbarItems too wide --> hide menu, show button
if (navbar.offsetWidth < navbarItems.scrollWidth) {
  // the navbar extends beyond the right edge of the screen
  // perform some modifications to the navbar
  document.getElementById('nav-button').classList.remove('hidden');
  document.getElementById('nav-items').classList.add('hidden');
// else --> show menu, hide button
} else {
  // the navbar fits within the screen
  // perform some other operation
  document.getElementById('nav-button').classList.add('hidden');
  document.getElementById('nav-items').classList.remove('hidden');
}

// add toggle button event
const navbarButton = document.getElementById('nav-button');
navbarButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // toggle dropdown
  document.getElementById('nav-items').classList.toggle('nav-items-mobile'); // --> add / remove nav-items-mobile class
  document.getElementById('nav-items').classList.toggle('hidden'); // show menu / hide menu
});
```

```css
/* if the child element is too long and overflows due to a maximum width, a scrollbar appears, and we can retrieve its maximum width using the "scrollWidth" property. */
nav {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* for normal view */
.nav-items {
  display: flex;
  gap: 4px;
}
/* for dropdown view */
.nav-items-mobile {
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

/* just design */
.nav-items > div {
  background-color: #555;
  color: #eee;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* for hide */
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Menu -->
<nav id="nav">
  <!-- Toggle Button -->
  <button id="nav-button" class="hidden">Open Menu</button>
  <!-- Menu Item List -->
  <div id="nav-items" class="nav-items">
    <div>Option 1</div>
    <div>Option 2</div>

    <!-- remove a few menu items to test whether the toggle button does not appear if the menu is not too wide -->
    <div>Option 3</div>
    <div>Option 4</div>
    <div>Option 5</div>
    <div>Option 6</div>
    <div>Option 7</div>
    <div>Option 8</div>
    <div>Option 9</div>
    <div>Option 10</div>
    <div>Option 11</div>
    <div>Option 12</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```